# To convert docs into HTML

Tags: java, html, converters, document

We are working on a Java Project and the requirement is that we need a HTML converter for normal office docs, which will convert the docs to HTML. Further we need to present those html pages in a viewer.

I got many solution but some convert only to doc, some to docx only, I need one single solution to convert doc, docx and other document converter into HTML.

Comment: Any good reason you are not going via PDF?

Comment: I need to show the documents in HTML Viewer only, if it possible to convert all kind of docs to PDF then to convert PDF then it can be fine.

Comment: "HTML viewer" - Do you mean a browser? Browsers have plugins for PDF. - What's so special in a "HTML viewer"?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it through Libre Office command line...

```
"'C:/Program Files/LibreOffice 4/program/soffice.exe' --headless --convert-to html --outdir converted/ 'uploads/filename.doc'");
```

Here `C:/Program Files/LibreOffice 4/program/soffice.exe` is tha path of the executable file...

You can download Libre Office from this link...

http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/

Comment: ohh okk.. but i think it'll be a very large code to write on our own.. even i had the same task last week, that's why i gave you this... as it is from command line i think it'll work with java too.. If you are interested make it a try...

Comment: @NeelamSharma Quite right: you can invoke soffice.exe from within your Java program.

Comment: Did you find a library for that yet? I got the same situation today. I need to do it in my java code instead of from command line. Of course, I could run the command from the code itself. But I'm looking for some kind of library.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Apache POI, there is a bunch of converting-classes.

[Link to the POI](http://poi.apache.org/)